# Is using the Keychain inherently insecure (when getting items back?)

Tags: cocoa, security

SecOps people disclaimer: I'm an informed amateur at this stuff. It's possible I'm misunderstanding something. If so, please advise :)

I'm doing some work with the Keychain/KeychainItemWrapper in my app. I want to store a user's password in a secure manner, and the Keychain seems like the way to do it.

However, I'm a little confused. I thought basic password security (modelled after unix `crypt()`) went something like this:

1. Encrypt and store user specified password, using an encryption algorithm that will give the same results every time (given the same salt)
2. At a later date, when the user enters their password, encrypt that too
3. Compare the two encrypted strings. Are they equal? The passwords must be the same

However, it appears that using KeychainItemWrapper (and maybe the entire Keychain API?) is meant towards giving the password as plain text back to the program. However, isn't that insecure? The unencrypted password is just sitting around in memory, waiting for someone to read it, right?

**The question**: What is the best pattern for storing passwords in Keychain, given my above worries about security and the fact that my program does not actually need to know the encrypted value? Or are my fears unfounded and I should stop worrying and learn to love the (unencrypted) password Keychain gives me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing two concepts (hashing vs encryption).

When you need to verify that someone knows a password, you hash it (w/ salt) and store that hash. Then, when someone tries to authenticate as that user, you ask them for the password, hash it with the same salt, and compare with the stored value. This is ideal as hashing is a one-way/non-reversible function. So, if someone accesses your credential store, they gain nothing as they would need to crack that hash (and modern algorithms like crypt/bcrypt are specifically designed to make brute force cracking very difficult).

However, if you need to be able to actually recover the plaintext password, you will encrypt the password instead of hashing it. Unlike cryptographic hashing, encryption is reversible, assuming you know the key.

The Keychain encrypts whatever you store in it with the assumption that you'll need to recover the actual data at some point (for example, if I put my Facebook password in a Keychain, it would be able to decrypt it and supply the actual password, when I need to use it to access Facebook). Keychain is designed to store those secret values encrypted, so that when you need to actually recover the original value you can.

Comment: +1 To reiterate in case it's not 100% clear: when something is authenticating to you, you only need the hash of the password. But when you are authenticating to something else, then you need the actual password. Most things put into Keychain are to allow you (the program) to authenticate to something else (a service), generally on behalf of your user.